# Passing Jquery Variable to PHP for database submission

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I am attempting to pass a Jquery variable to php in order to submit the variable value to my database. My php code, html code, and my jquery code are all in the same code file called entrysurvey.php. I have a radio button that is an image when it is being clicked the attribute is being used to define a jquery variable. This was successful, the alert portion of the code displays the correct variable number corresponding to the image. However, I was not successful in utilizing AJAX in order to pass it off to php yet. I have tried many different onSubmit functions but nothing has worked so far. Any help would be appreciated.

My Jquery code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

   var value
   $('img').click(function(){
      $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
     // var value = $(this).val();
     // alert(value);
   if($(this).attr("alt") == "first image"){

    value = "1";
    alert(value);




    
   } else if($(this).attr("alt") == "second image"){

    value = "2";
    alert(value);

   }else if($(this).attr("alt") == "third image"){

    value="3"
    alert(value);
   }else if($(this).attr("alt")== "fourth image"){

    value="4"
    alert(value);
   }else if($(this).attr("alt")=="fifth image"){

    value="5";
    alert(value);
       }else if($(this).attr("alt")=="sixth image"){

    value="6";
    alert(value);
   }else if($(this).attr("alt")=="seventh image"){

    value="7";
    alert(value);
   }



     $('.submitButton').click(function() { 
if (value != null) { //value is a variable so you can write it like this
    $.post('entrysurvey.php', {val: value}, function(response) { 
        alert(response); 
    }); 
} 
});





 

   });








   

   

 });






 </script>
```

HTML Code:

```html
     <form action="entrysurvey.php" method="POST" id="target">
     
    Select the image that you feel resembles your relationship with your pair the most: <br> <br>

      <table  cellpadding="20">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="radio"       name="oneness" value = "1" class="oneness"  > <br> <br> <br> <img src="images/1.png" height="200px" width="200px" class="selectedImage" alt="first image" > <br> <br></td>
            <td> <input type="radio" name="oneness" value = "2"  class="oneness" > <br> <br> <img src="images/2.png" height = "200px" width="200px" class="selectedImage" alt="second image" > <br> <br></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="oneness" value = "3"  class="oneness"  > <br> <br> <img src="images/3.png" height = "200px" width="200px" class="selectedImage" alt="third image" > <br> <br></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>

         <table cellpadding="20">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="oneness" value = "4"  class="oneness"  > <br> <br> <img src="images/4.png" height = "200px" width="200px" class="selectedImage" alt="fourth image" > <br> <br></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="oneness" value = "5"  class="oneness"  > <br> <br> <img src="images/5.png" height = "200px" width="200px" class="selectedImage" alt="fifth image" > <br> <br></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="oneness" value = "6"  class="oneness"  > <br> <br> <img src="images/6.png" height = "200px" width="200px" class="selectedImage" alt="sixth image"> <br> <br></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="oneness" value = "7"  class="oneness" > <br> <br> <img src="images/7.png" height = "200px" width="200px" class="selectedImage" alt="seventh image"> <br> <br></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
              
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submitButton">  
        </form>
```

Lastly this is the function I am using to attempt to pass it off to php.

```js
$('.submitButton').click(function(){ if($(value) != null){ $.post('entrysurvey.php', 'val=' + $(value).val(), function(response){ alert(response); }); } });
```

This is my PHP code:

!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```
<!-- language: lang-php-->
```

and still nothing happens unfortunately ios which is supposed to take the value of val is still null, and this is the error / response I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tle33.jpg)

Comment: Where is your ajax function?

Comment: $('.submitButton').click(function(){


   if($(value) != null){

    $.post('entrysurvey.php', 'val=' + $(value).val(), function(response){
     alert(response);
    });



   }
  });                                                                                                       This is it!

Comment: Please update you question with ajax function so others can read properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

you must post your ajax code! the problem, I guess, is that your value variable is declared inside if statement. This means that your variable's scope is only within your if statement. Try to declare it outside any statement, let me say

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var value;
   //the other part of code down here
```

You must be aware that you are posting your value variable as string, not as an integer, in case that this may serve

Comment: $('.submitButton').click(function(){


   if($(value) != null){

    $.post('entrysurvey.php', 'val=' + $(value).val(), function(response){
     alert(response);
    });



   }
  });                                                                                                                This is my function to pass it to php, I also edited the code to make sure that the variable is not within the if statement, still not working!

Answer (score 0):

Well I edited your ajax code because there are some errors!

```
$('.submitButton').click(function() { 
    if (value != null) { //value is a variable so you can write it like this
        $.post('entrysurvey.php', {val: value}, function(response) { 
            alert(response); 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

now the right syntax to send a variable to server is sending in a json format like this {val: value}! So you are sending the variable val to server and the value of this variable is the value of value variable. So since you are using post method you can use something like this in your entrysurvey.php file; $variable_name = $_POST['val'];
This way the php file will get the value you want to send!!!

Comment: I edited the code above to match your code but unfortunately the value of val is still null

Comment: well change the input type submit; Let it just be a button. When it's clicked, that's where the jquey ajax part comes in

Comment: and you can get rid of form tag, when you use ajax, it isn't mandatory to use form tag to transmit data to server